# How to properly customize c# record equality with inheritance

Tags: c#, c#-record-type

Given the following,

```cs
record Foo(int Id)
{
    public virtual bool Equals(Foo? foo)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"foo {(foo is null ? "IS" : "is NOT")} null");
      return foo is not null && Id == foo.Id;
    } 
    public override int GetHashCode() => Id.GetHashCode();
}

record FooSummary(int Id, string Summary) : Foo(Id);

record FooDetail(int Id,  string Detail) : Foo(Id);

var summary = new FooSummary(1, "Summary");      
var detail = new FooDetail(1, "Detail");

Console.WriteLine(detail == summary); 

// Output:
// foo IS null
// false
```

Is it possible to customize record equality is such a way that `detail == summary` is `true`?

In a class I could override `Equals(object obj)`, but in a record that results in a compilation error (CS0111)

**Edit**
I've accepted @StriplingWarrior's answer as it technically answers my question, but as he and others have explained: this is a bad idea.  This was definitely a case of the XY problem and trying to be a little *too* clever for my own good.

Comment: Why are you modifying Equals _in a record_?

Comment: How on Earth are these two things considered equal? What would be an example of a case where they are not equal?

Comment: @JohnWu: I'm assuming it's because the Id values are the same. If the Id values were not equal, the objects wouldn't be treated as equal. But I think it's clear that this is an abuse of the notion of object equality generally, and especially the notion of record equality. Whatever problem this is trying to solve should almost certainly be solved another way.

Comment: The short answer is no. `record`s give you a lot of implementation for free, including a sane definition of equality. If you want non-sane versions of equality, for whatever purpose, you'll have to write it yourself in an old-fashioned `class` or `struct`.

Comment: I like the value based equality semantics of records.  I just want to define _which_ values that should be considered.

Comment: You can do that, but what you cannot do is allow comparison between different types of records. The way that [equality members](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#equality-members) are defined for records puts a hard stop to that: comparing objects of different types goes to `object.Equals`, and for records that always does a `recordType.Equals(other as recordType)` call, which never succeeds if the types are siblings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can, by overriding the `==` operators.

```
public record Foo(int Id)
{
    public virtual bool Equals(Foo? foo)
    {
        return foo is not null && Id == foo.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Id.GetHashCode();
}

public record FooSummary(int Id, string Summary) : Foo(Id)
{
    public bool Equals(FooDetail? other)
    {
        return base.Equals((Foo?)other);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() => base.GetHashCode();
}

public record FooDetail(int Id, string Detail) : Foo(Id)
{
    public bool Equals(FooSummary? other)
    {
        return base.Equals((Foo?)other);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(FooDetail? left, FooSummary? right)
        => (object?)left == right || (left?.Equals(right) ?? false);
    public static bool operator !=(FooDetail? left, FooSummary? right)
        => !(left == right);
    public static bool operator ==(FooSummary? left, FooDetail? right)
        => (object?)left == right || (left?.Equals(right) ?? false);
    public static bool operator !=(FooSummary? left, FooDetail? right)
        => !(left == right);

    public override int GetHashCode() => base.GetHashCode();
}
```

That doesn't mean it's a good idea. You'll get unexpected behaviors when your types are *explicitly cast* as the specific types you're trying to compare.

In my experience, when people are tempted to override equality operators, that's usually the wrong tool for what they're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It is indeed not a good idea at all. If instead of `var` we use `Foo` for the types of the new records, the comparison fails. This *only* works if you very carefully compare only the concrete types, and then only through `==`. These subtleties are likely to go unnoticed until they actually break things.

Comment: The addition of the public `.Equals()` methods is especially nefarious (pardon the expression) because, while it makes expressions like `summary.Equals(details)` "work", in practice this is of no value because the only things that would call these methods in the first place are the overloaded `==` operators. None of the other ways `.Equals()` can be invoked in a generic fashion will ever resolve to these implementations. One of the best examples of "here's how you can sort of do this in a way that appears to work, but don't actually do it" I've seen -- no offense. :P

Comment: I totally agree. The things I've read about records make it _sound like_ it should be possible to define the EqualityContract, and as long as it's the same for all the types involved, it would be possible to create your own equality definition. But I can't see any path to actually make this work the way you'd expect it to.

Comment: `EqualityContract` sounds tempting but it's really only there to ensure comparisons between (in this case) `Foo` and `FooSummary` work in a symmetrical fashion. It can't be used as a generic mechanism for implementing equality across any two types you like, in particularly not sibling types.

Answer (score 2):

[C# 9 Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records) seems pretty clear:

> Two variables of a record type are equal if the record type definitions are identical, and if for every field, the values in both records are equal.

My read of this is that it leaves no room to customize equality for a `record` type.